# How to scroll scrollable AccessibilityNodeInfo nodes

Tags: android, scroll, accessibility

Using Android 4.2.2

I'm trying to write an AccessibilityService, and have most of the required features. I'm drawing on an overlay and allowing the user to select/cligk highlighted items via a bluetooth switch (the purpose is a disabled client wanting to interact with an android device using only one switch).

Whilst parsing a screen, I can get the root accessibiltyNodeInfo object, and all its children. I can highlight on the screen all such elements, and click a desired one by the .performAction() method.

On the home screen, there are 3 "panes" available, with the middle one being shown. Swipe left or right to see the others (standard launcher behaviour). There is a node that reports isScrollable = true, but the Action Flags do not report ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD or ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARDS. How do I scroll such a node, if I cannot call .performAction() on it as it does not support scrolling? Why does it report isScrollable = true if its not somehow scrollable?

Any help appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Is this the standard Launcher2 or an OEM-customized launcher?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot scroll a node that cannot perform ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD or ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARDS.

The Accessibility framework on Android is experimental at best and is plagued with inconsistencies such as the one you mentioned. In general, it is best not to rely on any of the `is[Property]()` methods. Instead, you should test for the property you are interested in yourself, after calling `getActions()` or `getActionsList()` on the node.